# Is there a special boot mode to boot into a system with root access (on Galaxy S)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, boot, root-access

What if the Samsung Galaxy S I've got has already been rooted?..

Is there perhaps a special boot mode which would boot into the system with root access?

Or normally, a "rooted" device always boots the system with complete root access?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a special boot for rooted devices AFAIK. Any rooted device necessarily boots with complete root access.

Comment: That's correct. Hover your mouse over the "root" tag chosen, and click the "info" link revealed in the popup. This will bring you to the [root tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/root/info), where you can find further details. (Remember this trick for other tags, too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want root access on a production phone, then you are going to have to use a root kit. There are a ton of benefits to having a rooted device, but there are also risks. Some devices are now coming out with the ability to run an app in root mode with user permission.

MY WORD OF CAUTION:

Attempting to root your device without proper knowledge will render it completely useless except for holding down your papers on a windy day. Make sure to do all instructions exactly and only flash your phone with builds that are meant to go with your specific device!

Best of luck!